# Using Auth Tokens to grant access to a specific item

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have an application which provides authenticated users with views into data about various objects in a database. There's another application in our ecosystem that provides different views into some of the same objects, using its own permission model. We trust that other application's permission model, and would like to allow them to issue access tokens to users who haven't been authenticated through our application's usual method, so those users can only view specific objects that the other application has verified they have access to.

Rather than coming up with our own spec for the communication between these two applications, I was wondering if there's already a standard approach available via something like OpenID Connect. OIDC seems to handle most of the gnarly details we'd have to consider in a case like this, but the one aspect where it doesn't seem to fit is that its access tokens seem to be general-purpose, rather than calling out a specific object that the user has access to. It says "Here's a user who can access your application", but not "Here's a user who can access Item 123".

Is there a standard for using an access token to grant access to a specific item, preferably using OAuth 2 and/or OpenID Connect? Am I correct in assuming that using an item's ID as a `scope` on the access token would be an inappropriate use of OAuth scopes?

Comment: In my reading I'm finding confirmation that `scope` is not a good candidate for holding a user's permission: Scopes [are for specifying which groups of claims](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#ScopeClaims) the app needs to have. But it [sounds like](https://community.auth0.com/t/permissions-in-access-token/23333/3) that data could be included in [namespaced Custom Claims](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/guides/create-namespaced-custom-claims).

Answer (score 0):

I've always found the best design for most real world apps to be like this:

- OAuth 2.0 based tech identifies the user
- You then lookup user details at an application level to enforce authorization

OAuth 2.0 scopes etc cannot handle things like this:

- You don't have access to account 123
- You don't have access to region US

So I tend to look them up from the user id in the token after login. This tends also to be much easier to extend, if for example the items and user rights in the external app grows over time.

For more concrete info see my write up on [API Claims Caching](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims).

Also [here is an example](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/host/oauth/authorizer.ts) of the coded algorithm in a Rest API, resulting in a claims object that can be [injected into logic classes](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/api/src/logic/services/companyService.ts).

In your case the custom claims provider would be the external app, and you could query claims from it, for data that does not really fit well into OAuth tokens.

Just my thoughts - not sure if it will fully work for you - but I've found this to be quite an adaptable solution, which often puts responsibilities in the right places.

Comment: That's generally the approach I take as well. It's the approach our application has taken so far. In this case, the source of truth for whether the user is authorized is a separate application. That application actually has a separate set of users _which will not be authenticated as normal users of our application_, nor have our normal authorization rules apply to them. For the subset of features that this separate group of users can access, we need them to have a token proving that they are allowed to use that application.

Comment: In theory we could use that token to query that app with each request, and let the app respond with information about whether that application's authorization rules would allow them to see the given resource. But there are benefits to having the token itself include enough authorization information to avoid the need for those extra round-trips.

Comment: Interesting scenario. I think I would aim to handle it via a claims caching design where your back end API asks the other app for rules - but only when a token is first received - to ensure good performance. It would be similar to how API gateways do introspection requests, and also easy to extend. I have edited the above answer to point to a couple of links.